# ngClass with string interpolation to dynamically change it

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular

I need to change with variables the classes applied to a div, but not all. In the following example I need a class to be changed based on a string named color, so I tried string interpolation. Throws error, and just using the variable name doesn't work... How should I do it?

```
<div [ngClass]="'progress-bar progress-bar-striped active {{color}}'" role="progressbar" [style.width]="progress">
</div>
```

Comment: Is value of color the name of the class?

Comment: yes, it is a long name that changes based on a lot of logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this syntax:

```
<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped" [ngClass]="[color, size]" >...</div>
```

Also try this

```
<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped" [className]="color">...</div>
```

Comment: Well it worked with [ngClass]="color" but what if I need to use more than one variable... I can't make it work with [ngClass]="color, size" for example.

Comment: You still can do newClass="color size" and then [ngClass]="newClass"

Comment: Or   [ngClass]="[color, size]"

Comment: Great! I used your last option and mixed with the regular class names like this [ngClass]="['progress-bar', 'progress-bar-striped', color, size]". Thanks a lot

Comment: I am glad that worked :) I would still keep the 'static' part out of ngClass and keep it for the 'dynamic' part

Answer (score 1):

your variable is inside the static string and cannot be parsed as a variable.
Use this instead :

```
<div [ngClass]="'progress-bar progress-bar-striped active '+color" role="progressbar" [style.width]="progress">
</div>
```

Notice that the space after the active class and the + after the closing quote

Comment: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected

Comment: Oops, forgot to remove the {{}} as they are not needed here!

Comment: Not working. There is no syntax error but the class is not being applied.

Comment: If the color variable has no value at the beginning, it is quite normal. try to print to the console the value of color when you expect it to have a value, and then inpect the element to see if the class is added.
Also, color needs to be a declared as a css class

Comment: color is indeed declared as a css class as it is a bootstrap class 'progress-bar-success' for example.